# Balancing spell slots of level greater than 9th

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wizard

Assume there is such amulet existing in the world:

- Wearer Wizard can cast 2 extra lvl 10 spells every day
- Wearer Wizard can cast 1 extra lvl 11 spell every day
- If you find spells of such level you could use them with such slots (I.E. Quest spells)
- If you don't find such spells you can anyway put metamagic spells inside that slots.

Am I allowed by 3.5 rules to have metamagic spells at those levels? (I.E. Am I Allowed to "**Extend Time Stop**" and put it on one of those slots?)

Comment: This seems like multiple questions. One about if you are allowed to do certain things and one about whether it's balanced to create a certain magic item. I recommended asking them separately.

Comment: I've removed the second question about the sword; you should ask that separately.

Comment: Ok I'm fine with that ^^. I'm mostly interested in the metamagic part anyway :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 9th-level or lower spell modified by metamagic feats can be prepared in or cast using a 10th-level or higher spell slot of the appropriate level. Getting such higher-than-9th-level slots is the whole point of the epic feat [**Improved Spell Capacity**](http://dndsrd.net/epicFeats.html#improved-spell-capacity) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 210), after all.

However, there are no published 10th-level or higher spells; those slots above 9th are *exclusively* for spells modified by metamagic. Further, as it sort of provides the benefits of *three epic feats*, I'd expect such an amulet to have a *very* high price!